# I get blank activity opened when starting new activity

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-intent, android-activity

I am using [this library](https://github.com/yanzhenjie/Album) for multiple image selection. After the user finish selecting the photos, another activity (`current_location.class`) should start.

Here is my code to do that:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == OPEN_MEDIA_PICKER) {
            // Make sure the request was successful
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                selectionResult = data.getStringArrayListExtra("result");
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), currentLocation.class);
                intent.putExtra("selectedMedia", selectionResult);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }
```

new activity is successfully started but its blank!

Below is my `currentLocation.java`  Activity:

```
public class currentLocation extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        setContentView(R.layout.current_location);
    }
}
```

and here is the `current_location.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_view">
    
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

it should have background color, I tried adding buttons as well, but I always get blank activity started

is the problem from the way I am starting new activity? or from the way I am setting the `xml` layout to the `currentLocation` class?

Comment: paste your `@drawable/bg_view` file

Comment: @Source we need to see bg_view to make sure we know why nothing is displaying.

Comment: @Yashasvi I am using @drawable/bg_view in my fragment background and it works, and when I see the design preview on my current_location.xml, I can see the background applied

Comment: @WadeWilson the background works in my fragment and I could see it in the preview on current_location.xml. shouldn't the file be fine if it works with other views?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try changing your `onCreate` method.
use the following instead:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.current_location);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), currentLocation.class);`
with
`Intent intent = new Intent(this.getActivity(), currentLocation.class);`

---

Also Check if `<activity android:name=".currentLocation">` is there in manifest.

Comment: when I try 'this' instead of 'getActivity' it shows me an error. and I have <activity android:name=".currentLocation"> in my Manifest

Comment: the error is 'cannot resolve constructor PostActivity, currentLocation'

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it doesn't matter but I would've tried two things to lower the chance of an error.

1. I would use putStringArrayListExtra() on the intent if you get an StringArrayListExtra from the activity result data intent
2. I would work with the specific activity/fragment context when creating the new intent.
   E.g. new Intent(className.this, currentLocation.class); 
   OR new Intent(className.this.getActivity(), currentLocation.class);